# Avoid automatic framework linking in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, dyld

I have an [example project](https://github.com/Usipov/SwiftAutoFrameworksLinkage) consisting of a main target (`LinkerTests`) and a dependent dynamic framework (`Dynamic`).

If you run the project, you will see the following dyld binary load:

```
dyld: loaded: {DerivedDataPath}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dynamic.framework/Dynamic
```

This dyld binary load happens due to `import Dynamic` in `AppDelegate.swift` despite of the following:

1. `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase is empty
2. `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK` is set to false

What I need to achieve is avoiding this automatic implicit linking. 
Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

---

Related question: [Don't we need to link framework to XCode project anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902787/dont-we-need-to-link-framework-to-xcode-project-anymore)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently this feature is called autolinking. Swift compiler implicitly emits additional linker flags that links in all the modules the source code depends on (`import Dynamic`).

There is no way to disable this entirely. But there is a private compiler flag that allows you to disable autolinking for a single framework: `swiftc -disable-autolink-framework <framework>`.

Some references:
https://gist.github.com/zrzka/c89705ff634ea01aebc1
https://github.com/niw/automatic_linking_tool/blob/master/README.md

I’m pretty sure you can append `-v` to `swiftc` and it will print all underlying invocations as commands. Hopefully you’ll be able to see the linker invocations as well.

You should wrap the the private flag inside two `-Xfrontend` flags to allow it to be used:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-Xfrontend -disable-autolink-framework -Xfrontend Dynamic"
```

For this to take effect you must still set **Link Frameworks Automatically** No under Apple Clang - Language - Modules.